# Перевод строки в последовательность единиц и нулей

Tags: java, строки

Подскажите, как перевести символстроку из вида "буквастрока" (кириллица) в последовательность из единиц и нулей?

Comment: Единички-нулики это видимо двоичное представление... детский сад какой-то. Жесть

Comment: палочек и кружочков

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Очень просто:

```
String.format("%16s", Integer.toBinaryString(s.charAt(0))).replace(" ", "0");
```

Comment: Вооо, спасибо:)